# Is there a way of loading the .env files without building a new lib?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need the `.env` file's content to auto-generate some stuff; and I'm looking to see if there's a loader that exists. Note that this needs to happen through a pre-build commandlet, so react's own bundling isn't needed.

Something like:

```js
import { loader } from 'env-loader';

console.log(loader.loadEnv()['REACT_APP_SOME_SETTING']) // some setting!
```

Comment: `dotenv`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @Konrad yeah - that worked alright. Do you wanna post that as an answer?